# Is there way to calculate the outer product of arrays avoiding exceeds memory (R platform)?

Tags: r, memory, product

I want to calculate the outer product of arrays for large data by using outer function, however, I hit RAM/memory limits (> 5G).

For example, is there a way to calculate the outer product of arrays  avoiding exceeds memory and then get the value of each pair (x-y) below 100.

```
x <- 1:9000
y <- 2:80000

mat <- outer(x,y,"*") #>3G
matpair <- as.data.frame(which(mat <= 100, arr.ind = TRUE))
matpair <- as.matrix(tidyr::complete(matpair, col = 1:ncol(mat)))
```

Comment: Which is the step that exceeds memory limits, `outer()` or `complete()`?

Comment: @SamR, Yes, mat from Outer function